# How can I build an internet download manager in Java?

Tags: java, http

I am building an Internet Download Manager using java.

How do I get the file size from server? Also, is there a way to divide the file into partitions so that I can download them in parallel?

Comment: I have posted an entry about this topic on my blog. Hope it will help you http://luugiathuy.com/2011/03/download-manager-java/

Answer (score 2):

First part of your Question:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

`URL.openConnection().getContentLength()`